# Excel VBA Cell Format

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a simple tracking spreadsheet for myself with a userform interface, learning from lots of different online tutorials as I've never coded before. 
Using the excel ribbon, I have set certain cells with a certain format, one for dates (Day Month Year) & one for currency ([$$-en-AU]-#,##0.00;[Red]-[$$-en-AU]-#,##0.00).

My issue is: whenever I enter data into textbox6, textbox20 textbox21 & textbox22, then close the userform, transferring all the entered data into the worksheet. 
The data entered into the above textboxes overrides how the cell is formatted. 
Is there any way to lock the cell format or make it use a certain format regardless of what the user enters into the text box?

This is the code that is used when adding the data into the sheet & unloading the userform:
    `Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'Copy input values to sheet.
    Dim rw As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim LO As ListObject
    Dim LEO As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets("2020_Data")
    Set LO = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    'lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B") .End(xlUp). .Offset(1, 0) .Row
    With LO.Range.Columns(2)
        Set LEO = .Find(what:="", after:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
            searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext)
        If Not LEO Is Nothing Then
            lrow = LEO.Row
    '        MsgBox LEO.Row 'First empty row at column B
        End If
    End With
    'rw = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookInValues) .Row + 1
    With ws
        .Cells(lrow, "B") = Me.TextBox6
        .Cells(lrow, "C") = Me.TextBox21
        .Cells(lrow, "F") = Me.ComboBox2
        .Cells(lrow, "G") = Me.ComboBox3
        .Cells(lrow, "I") = Me.TextBox16
        .Cells(lrow, "H") = Me.TextBox17
        .Cells(lrow, "J") = Me.TextBox18`

Comment: Please include the code you have tried using in your question and explain the problems you ran across using it.

Comment: HI braX, i haven't tried any code as yet, only using the cell number/date format option in the excel ribbon. I have edited my question to reflect this. Thanks

Comment: It is almost certainly an issue with the code though, specifically the part that dumps the values from the textboxes. If I had to guess, you're doing `Range(A2) = textbox` instead of `Range(A2).Value = textbox.Value`

Comment: Hi Brax, I've edited my original question to include the code that is used when the userform is unloaded. Would you mind pointing out where I went wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my previous comment, the problem is:
`.Cells(lrow, "B") = Me.TextBox6`

As a rule of thumb, when you want to modify only the value of a cell with VBA, you should use `.Cells(...).Value` Otherwise, you'll likely override some properties (in this case, formatting)

Using `Me.TextBox.6` is not ideal, and I prefer being explicit as well in this case (even if this will work just fine). So, all in all:

`.Cells(lrow, "B").Value = Me.Textbox6.Value`

Comment: Oh I think I understand the properties behind the code now and how Range works. Thank you for your help, It's all working now! :)

Comment: @new11: If the answer solved (in a way) your problem, ticking the check box to the left code side, to make it the accepted answer, would not kill anybody...

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, I had no idea that was how it all worked. I've ticked it now, thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: Hi @Harry, the data that is entered into the text box of the userform now keeps the format of the cells since following your advice. However, I have noticed that the format date is not kept in certain situation's. 
For example; when I enter the date as: “1 Jan 2020” the cell format corrects this to a long date, however, when for a second time I enter a date into the textbox as “01/01/2020” the format of the cell does not correct it a long date. Would anyone have any idea how I could fix this? Thanks again everyone!